# Filter list based on component's data

Tags: r

I am using R to do this task, but cannot figure how to do it. 
I have a list with many data frames. All the data frames have the same column names.

For example,

```
My list
   Jan.2014
       $School
       $Subject
       $Country
       $Student.Name
       $Score
   Feb.2014
       $School
       $Subject
       $Country
       $Student.Name
       $Score
```

And the list goes on to Dec.2016. In this case, I want to filter the list based on the value in the data frames and subset it to a data.frame... For example, show me every entry that is "School = ABC High School" and put them in a data frame.

I have a feeling that I need to use lapply function for this task, but I don't know which function to include and how to include the "searching value" in lapply function.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that

Comment: @akrun Expected output would be a subset data frame of all the data frames in a list for which a value satisfies the given condition. If I want to apply the condition just for one data frame in a list, it is easy to write a code like My.list$Jan.2014[My.list$Jan.2014$School == "ABC High School"]... but then if I want to repeat the process for all data frames in the list... I don't know how to go about doing it.

Comment: something like lapply(my.list, FUN = function(x) x[x$School == ABC, ]) followed by a do.call may work